# How do I control the gain of the output?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have created an Audio context with an oscillator but I can't control the gain of the output, even with `gainNode.gain.value` :

```
var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;  
var audioctx = new AudioContext();
var gainNode = audioctx.createGain();

var oscillator = audioctx.createOscillator(); 
var oscillator2 = audioctx.createOscillator();

oscillator.connect(audioctx.destination);
oscillator.start(0);
gainNode.connect(audioctx.destination);
gainNode.gain.value = 0;
```

Comment: Please provide more details/errors for what is not working. What is your specific question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect the oscillator to the gain node, not the destination:

```
oscillator.connect(gainNode);
oscillator.start(0);
gainNode.connect(audioctx.destination);
gainNode.gain.value = 0;
```